# Add two form fields in Django

Tags: python, django

I have two CharFields in my forms.py FirstName and LastName and a CharField FullName in my models.py file.

How do I add the two (FirstName and LastName) and store them as FullName?

I tried doing it in forms.py (not working), so the only other option is to change it after the POST request in views.py but am unsure how to alter its contents.

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    FullName = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=2000)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.FullName
```

forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    FirstName = forms.CharField()
    LastName = forms.CharField()
    balance = forms.IntegerField(initial=2000,help_text="")

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        url = cleaned_data.get('url')
        if url and not url.startswith('http://'):
            url = 'http://' + url
            cleaned_data['url'] = url

        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('FullName', 'balance')
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    game_list = Game.objects.all()
    context_dict = {'games': game_list}
    profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)
        context_dict = {'games': game_list, 'profile_form':profile_form}

        print profile_form

        if profile_form.is_valid():

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)

            profile.save()
            registered = True

        else:
            print profile_form.errors

    return render_to_response('/', context_dict, context)
```

Comment: is that a modelform or a simple form? say, does that form has other fields of this model to accomodate? maybe show some code

Comment: Why not just show a field for `FullName`? You'll be introducing potential headaches when users want to edit their `UserProfile`. How will you differentiate between a `FirstName` and `LastName` of `"Name1 Name2"` and `"Name3"`, and a `FirstName` and `LastName` of `"Name1"` and `"Name2 Name3"`?

Comment: The design of the app is such that it necessitates such a process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to override the save method of the form, populating the instance fullname field

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    FirstName = forms.CharField()
    LastName = forms.CharField()
    balance = forms.IntegerField(initial=2000,help_text="")

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        url = cleaned_data.get('url')
        if url and not url.startswith('http://'):
            url = 'http://' + url
            cleaned_data['url'] = url

        return cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        profile = super(UserProfileForm, self).save(commit=False)
        profile.set_fullname(self.cleaned_data["FirstName"], self.cleaned_data["LastName"])
        if commit:
            profile.save()
        return profile 

   class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('balance')
```

then in the `UserProfile` model you will have a `set_fullname` method to implement that logic as you want, for example:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # various things ...
    def set_fullname(self, f_name, l_name):
        self.FullName = f_name + ' ' + l_name
```

Also I'm ignoring the view part, because I think it is just a stub and need big improvements.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly. :)